# How to insert an initial values for the list, which have already added data in it, mvc, c#

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller, insert, dropdownlistfor

I have added data to a list like this.

```
List<CommonSearch> regionList = new List<CommonSearch>();

            foreach(var items in filteredRegion)
            {
                regionList.Add(new CommonSearch 
                {
                    Destination = returnRegionName(items),
                    regCde = items
                });

            }
```

now I want to add initial data for this.like below to show in my dropdownlist.how can I do that.

//regionList.Insert(0,"All");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert into `regionList` new `CommonSearch` item after `foreach` loop:

```
regionList.Insert(0, new CommonSearch() { Destination = "All" });
```

Your insert code won't work because of type mismatch in your list.

Comment: job done, thanx.I will accept your answer in 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

`List<>` does guarantee ordering, you could either add element at the beginning.

```
List<CommonSearch> regionList = new List<CommonSearch>();
regionList.Add(new CommonSearch { Destination = "All" });
```

or insert at `0`th location after your loop.

```
regionList.Insert(0, new CommonSearch { Destination = "All" });
```